# Can I join between two MySQL tables stores on separate machines?

Tags: mysql

I have a relatively light query that needs information from a local MySQL table along with another MySQL table which is stored on a physically separate machine (on the same network).  I'm keen to avoid setting up replication just to facilitate this light query that only needs executed once a day.

Is there any way that I can join with a table on a remote machine using one query?  Or run a SELECT INTO into a local table.

---

**Notes**

- I'm using C# & .NET 4.

Comment: I don't believe you can as you need to create a single connection to a mysql database with your script. What language are you using?

Comment: C# & .NET 4 - I've also updated the question to note that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the FEDERATED storage engine for the remote table. [Find out more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html).